# How to render ListView using ReactNativeMeteor

Tags: user-interface, meteor, react-native

How can I use List/ListItem from react-native-elements to display the list below using Meteor/ReactNative and the map function?

In their doc, they say:

```
<List containerStyle={{marginBottom: 20}}>
  {
    list.map((l, i) => (
      <ListItem
        roundAvatar
        avatar={{uri:l.avatar_url}}
        key={i}
        title={l.name}
      />
    ))
  }
</List>
```

Here are my components

```
const DeputyDetail =({deputy})=>{
  const{nom, groupe_sigle} = deputy;
  return(
    <Text>Nom : {nom}, {groupe_sigle}</Text>
  );
}


class Deputies_List extends Component{
  render(){
    const {deputies}= this.props;  
    return(
      <View>
        {this.props.deputies.map(deputy=><DeputyDetail deputy={deputy.depute} key={deputy._id}/>)}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. Do you want your `<DeputyDetail>` component to appear as each item in a `<List>`?

Comment: Yes , DeputyDetail should appear for each item